# polymorphism in haskell - using multiple versions of one function without giving it different names

Tags: haskell, polymorphism, dry

the other day I wrote a small program to collect a bunch of numbers in a matrix - `data Matrix = Matrix [[Int]]` starting at a corner - `Corner` and follow a Path - `[Direction]` all of the three types are instance of a class `Transformable`

then i have a function that generates a transformation function, that turns a given corner and direction - to `LeftUp` and `Right`

```
turnLUR :: Transformable a => (Corner, Direction) -> a -> a
```

then i use this function to "harvest" all the numbers in the matrix:

```
harvest :: Matrix → [(Corner,Direction)] → [Int]
harvest _ [] = []
harvest (Matrix []) _ = []
harvest as (cd:csds) = b ++ harvest (Matrix bs) csds'  --cd = (Corner,Direction)
                     where f1 = turnLUR cd -- Matrix -> Matrix
                           f2 = turnLUR cd -- Corner -> Corner
                           f3 = turnLUR cd -- Direction -> Direction
                           Matrix (b:bs) = f1 as -- b = first line of [[Int]]
                           fcfd (c,d) = (f2 c,f3 d)
                           csds' = map fcfd csds
```

Now my question why do I have to write down `f1`, `f2` and `f3` instead of using one function `f` three times (keeping DRY in my mind!) - all three types `Corners`, `Directions` and `Matrix` are instances of the `class Transformable`.

How would I write that code without - making three versions of the "same" function?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is because of the [*monomorphism restriction*](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Monomorphism_restriction). Give it an explicit type signature, and you'll be able to reuse the same function each time:

```
harvest :: Matrix → [(Corner,Direction)] → [Int]
harvest _ [] = []
harvest (Matrix []) _ = []
harvest as (cd:csds) = b ++ harvest (Matrix bs) csds'  --cd = (Corner,Direction)
                     where f :: Transformable a => a -> a
                           f = turnLUR cd
                           Matrix (b:bs) = f as -- b = first line of [[Int]]
                           fcfd (c,d) = (f c,f d)
                           csds' = map fcfd csds
```

Alternatively, you can turn it off by putting `{-# LANGUAGE NoMonomorphismRestriction #-}` at the top of your file.

The monomorphism restriction isn't well-liked — even GHC's manual refers to it as the [dreaded monomorphism restriction](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/users_guide/monomorphism.html) — but there are some tricky corner cases, especially related to sharing (see the wiki page I linked for more information), that it avoids. In this case, I'd recommend just adding the type signature.

Comment: Note that the monomorphism restriction only affects functions written in pointless style (as well as values that aren't functions), so if you define `f` using explicit parameters, it won't be affected by the restriction even if you don't give it a type signature.

Comment: so is the type signature `f :: Transformable a => a -> a` keeping the function being specified to a type signature; and without it the compiler deduces `f` to be of type `Matrix -> Matrix` as it is its first usage. Thank you very much for clarifying this. Especially i didn't know that the signature could resolve this monomorphism restriction.